# How does this ultrasound transmitter work?

Tags: transmitter, ultrasound, transducer

[image]

Can anyone explain each component and why it is used?
Why Q dash used instead of Q from IC 74121?
why .1 nad 47 microfarad used?
how the 0 to 9V and 0 to -100 V obtained?

reference site
https://www.instructables.com/Body-ultrasound-Sonography-With-Arduino/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What is the Arduino trigger and how can it applied?

Comment: Have you tried looking up the individual components to see what they do?  The datasheets of the integrated circuits are very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a stab at a circuit description.

The 7805 is a linear regulator.  Its purpose is to regulate the 9 V input down to 5 V for the 74121 monostable (one-shot).

The 74121 looks like it takes an enable from the Arduino, and provides a fixed-width and frequency pulse train (though adjustable with the 10 k pot) to the 7667 MOSFET gate driver. The driver's purpose is to provide enough current and voltage to switch the IRL620 on and off quickly from the logic-level output of the 74121..

The boost converter is a switch-mode power supply that converts the 9 V to 100 V to provide the necessary high voltage to the transducer.

The IRL620 is a power MOSFET that with the pull-up (3 k resistor) provides a 0-100 V pulse that's AC coupled through the 100 nF capacitor to drive the transducer.  The 50 ohm resistor may be built in to the transducer, since if it weren't there the drive voltage could be a lot lower than 100 V.

Comment: How this 0 to -100V is got and why it is ?

Comment: The boost converter changes the 9 V to 100 V, and the IRL620 acts as a switch, to switch it on and off.  I assume your transducer is piezoelectric, and the specifications of the transducer require the given voltage level.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the circuitry has been explained by John D in his answer.

Focusing on the output part only. The 100nF/200V cap is charged through the 3k and 50hm resistors to 100V. When the circuit is triggered, the output MOSFET discharges the cap, and a -100V pulse (with respect to ground) is sent to the transducer. It works in the same way as hitting a tuning fork: the piezo element of the transducer continues resonating at its mechanical resonant frequency with exponentially decaying amplitude. Typical frequencies are in the low MHz range. The length of the excitation pulse (and thus the energy) can be adjusted with the 10k pot.

Answering some of your further questions:

- The 9V is provided by some power supply, but can be a battery too.
- The 100V is produced by a switched-mode power supply module. The original link is dead, you can get similar modules from China webshops.
- The component values were obviously not scientifically calculated. They're reasonable and usual standard values, picked without much thinking.
- The inverted output of the 74121 needs to be used because the ICL7667 gate driver is an inverting type. This way the polarity of the MOSFET control signal is correct: it's positive during the excitation pulse and zero otherwise.

Comment: How can I connect the probe to receiving and transmitting module?
can anyone suggest the connector for this purpose